# How do I download and install GNU Fortran compiler? Or should I use codeblocks?

Tags: cygwin, fortran, codeblocks, gnu, gfortran

I'm having trouble navigating GNU's website and finding the necessary files. And I strongly suspect the installation process isn't going to be straightforward given how their website is designed.

Or should I use Codeblocks instead?

Do I also need to install Cygwin since I'm running Windows 7?

(I have prior, basic experience with C, Matlab and Wolfram Mathematica programming)

Comment: codeblocks is an IDE, not a compiler

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded gfortran-windows-20140523.exe from http://users.humboldt.edu/finneyb/gfortran-windows-20140523.exe as suggested on https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#Windows and was able to install gfortran from this binary on Windows 8.1 and to compile a Fortran program. Gfortran --version says 4.9.0 20131208 (experimental)